# Cloudfront not compressing Transfer-encoding chunked

Tags: nginx, amazon-web-services, cdn, amazon-cloudfront

My setup looks like this: User->Cloudfront->Nginx->gunicorn

Apparently nginx, doesn't compress (gzip) when there is a CDN inbetween (Via header present) so my nginx sends:

```
Transfer-encoding: chunked
```

and according to HTTP/1.1 Content-length is not allowed when it is chunked. Since cloudfront doesn't see content-length header, it doesn't compress neither and my user gets non-compressed responses.

I did

```
gzip_proxied    no-cache no-store private expired auth;
```

to make sure nginx compresses even though there is a CDN inbetween but this felt like a hack.. Is my cloudfront configuration wrong, or is it weird that my nginx sends chunked?

What am I doing obviously wrong as the default values result in user getting non-compressed files?

Comment: tried `gzip_proxied any`  and do you have `gzip on;
    gzip_disable "msie6";` too?

Comment: It works when I do `gzip_proxied` but I want to know why default values cause undesired behaviour, I feel like something else is wrong with my setup. Why does nginx send `chunked` content? is it normal?

Comment: Could not confirm you for sure, but `chunked` is part of http/1.1 and seems normal

Comment: have you looked at those explanations here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5280633/gzip-compression-of-chunked-encoding-response